# Can you prevent another app from opening within your app

Tags: ios

Wierd question, and may sound extremely dumb, but theoretically could you stop another app opening (infect it with a bug) for a certain period of time on the click of a button in your app?

Comment: Apps don't open within other apps. What do you mean? But no, one app has no control at all over other apps.

Comment: Exactly. iOS apps are totally sandboxed. Maybe you want to prevent the mechanism that allows an app to call and open another one? Like when inside an app you tap on a link and it does open Safari?

Comment: Thanks guys. Thought it was a longshot.